# How to limit results by user globally in Eloquent?

Tags: slim, eloquent, slim-3, global-scope

I am using eloquent as part of a slim 3 project with slim-jwt-auth (https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth), outside of Laravel. There are many situations where I want to control the items returned based on the user who is making the request.

From what I understand though, there is no way to add extra parameters such as `user_id` for use in eloquent global scope.

I found one blog post that initially looked helpful,
 as it does exactly what I am trying to achieve (http://www.sdavara.com/Eloquent-Global-Scopes-A-cool-and-easy-way-to-fetch-loggedin-user-data/), but it relies on Laravel Auth.

The fact that my solution needs to work globally is important, as I have many nested relationships that should also be filtered by user id when queried.

Could anyone suggest what might be the best approach for achieving this?

Comment: You basically need a way to detect which user is currently sending the request, then you want to add global scope to eloquent models to filter queries based on some user properties, like user_id, right?

Comment: basically.  I have a user object as part of my request, decoded from jwt in middleware, but eloquent doesn't allow me to pass parameters  to global scope definitions, so I am not sure how I can define it.